# Error building project with XNAnimationPipline.dll and XNA3.1

Tags: animation, xna, xnanimation

I have a model with 2 animations, created in Blender and exported to fbx.

Referencing the XNAnimation.dll works, however when I reference the XNAnimationPipline.dll in the Content project I get a build error.

```
The "BuildContent" task failed unexpectedly. 
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XNAnimationPipeline, Version=0.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0c21691816f8c6d0' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.
    File name: 'XNAnimationPipeline, Version=0.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0c21691816f8c6d0'
```

I have recently upgraded to XNA3.1 and am using the latest XNAnimation library.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can someone add the "xnanimation" tag. It wont let me because i'm a "new user"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebuilding the source code sorts it out

[This explains](http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/37939/220793.aspx#220793)